# Can a blockchain be Centralised? Will it be called as Blockchain if it is centralised?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, ethereum, corda

I was reading lot of articles on blockchain and almost everyone has some different understanding of blockchain.
Is there any accepted definition of Blockchain by any community?

In few articles I read:

- Blockchains are Decentralised while DLTs are not.
- All blockchains are DLT but not all DLTs are blockchain. It added "if transactions get stored in blocks then it is a blockchain else it is not"

From above statements-
Is Decentralisation must for a Blockchain?
Or it is just a Immutable Distributed Database? which can be centralised or decentralised?

Comment: do you have any reference which states this? As I also thought that it is must but I don't have any reference.

Comment: I'm gonna take back on that. After a few researches, I found out there ARE also centralized blockchains (which is a shock to me. We were all told that Blockchains are supposed to be decentralized). Refer to - https://www.recordskeeper.co/blog/centralized-vs-decentralized-blockchain/

Comment: Yeah Ripple is centralised blockchain.

Comment: @NeonNatureEX thanks! Actually, the reason is, there is no single explanation in which all agree that's why lots of confusion.

Comment: Ripple is not centralized in the physical sense. Not only can there be, but there are distributed notes for Ripple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would refer you to the first blockchain application, Bitcoin, which describes the "chain of blocks" in the original [Bitcoin Whitepaper](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf).

### Blockchain

The term “blockchain” is often overused, that can have different meanings in different contexts. Blockchain technology has 3 major components that together really make it an innovation. Strictly speaking, a blockchain is just a data structure similar to a linked list. Blocks of data reference their previous block by including their digital fingerprint or hash in their block of data. If a previous block is modified, then all the following hashes will be different and it is easy to detect if the data has been tampered with. Even more importantly, is that this establishes an order to when events took place, in the case of Bitcoin, these events are transactions. The final piece is a consensus mechanism that allows participants on a publicly distributed network to all agree on a chain of blocks.

### Consensus

A consensus mechanism extends the blockchain data structure by providing rules (agreed to by network participants) that enforce how blocks are accepted by the network as a whole. For example, with the proof-of-work consensus, there is an agreed-upon amount of work that must be done before a block is accepted as valid (its hash must meet a maximum value threshold). The lower the threshold, the more work must have been done (on average) to calculate the block hash. Providing a valid block hash becomes proof of work. This can make it much more difficult to modify past blocks, as the same amount of work must be done in order for the network to accept it as valid, thus distributed consensus can be achieved. **This is why “blockchain technology” was invented, to achieve distributed consensus without relying on a third party.** “Blockchain technology” is not really that interesting without the proof-of-work component and so it depends on what your definition of “blockchain technology” happens to be.

In conclusion, by this definition of blockchain, it doesn't make sense to use blockchain in a centralized environment (it is for ***distributed*** consensus).

Comment: What do mean by "it is for distributed consensus"? Are you referring that DLTs are centralised and centralised blockchain don't make sense?

Comment: blockchain is a solution to the problem of achieving consensus in a distributed network, that is its purpose. A centralized blockchain doesn't make sense. Blockchain is just one implementation of a DLT, which doesn't make sense to be centralized either (DLT means Distributed Ledger Technology, not Centralized Ledger Technology)

Answer (score 0):

One of the best writings on centralization and decentralization is an article by Ethereum creator Vitalik Buterin.

https://medium.com/@VitalikButerin/the-meaning-of-decentralization-a0c92b76a274

In this article he explains how even the most decentralized systems are also centralized to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

Let's firstly make it clear that what is decentralization.

> Decentralisation is the process by which the activities of an organization, particularly those regarding planning and decision making, are distributed or delegated away from a 
>   central, authoritative location or group. Concepts of decentralization have been 
>   applied to group dynamics and management science in private businesses and organizations, 
>   political science, law and public administration, economics, money and technology.  -- WikiPedia

So basically, there's no central, authoritative person or group or whatever to make decisions or plans in a decentralized system. According to this, I personally would prefer to separate it into two essential levels of a blockchain system.

In terms of the blockchain system(software and hardware) itself, it is decentralized. Because it is based on a distributed computer system, and it also has consensus algorithm (POW, POS, DAG etc.) to make sure each node/party in the system can reach to consistency.

In terms of governance, it can be decentralized or centralized. A typical centralized blockchain system is the private blockchain, since it is governed/managed by a single group or organization. While, obviously, a public blockchain is decentralized on the other hand.

Answer (score 0):

Blockchain is a distributed ledger of Information. The main Concept was taken from the paper of Digital Time Stamping by Stuart Harber. The idea behind blockchain is to remove the centralized System so the decission power is taken from single Entity. Now if you want to make it centralised you are basically doing a trade off of the Basic properties of blockchain.

If you make the blockchain centralised one of the key feature is the consenses where other nodes verify the trnsactions so in centralised System the whole work is done by one node and we can assure that if that node is trustworthy node.

Answer (score 0):

According to Arrifin and Subramanian (2022), blockchain is of three types: public, private, and consortium or federated. While the public blockchain allows reading and engaging in transactions to be done by anyone, following the presence of transparency and anonymity, the private blockchain is closed and limited to one organization. Lastly, the federated or consortium blockchain ensures that access and permission are controlled by a group of entities.

Also, with the definitions of internet, intranet, and extranet, one can easily understand that a blockchain can also leverage centralization.
Extranet: An extranet is a private intranet extended to authorized users of an external organization.
Intranet: An intranet is a hub for internal communications, allowing your organization to easily and effectively share company-wide announcements and policy updates
Internet: The Internet connects computers to provide information using a communication protocol called TCP/IP

In conclusion, one needs to first understand the domain of application before querying the answer. E.G. A consortium should be able to leverage centralization in some of its operations.

REFERENCE

1. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=9970827

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Block-chain is a distributed, decentralized, public ledger.

Comment: there are centralised blockchains also